# Create UIPickerView NSArray out of bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to create a emoji UIPikcerView.Here's part of my code:

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     _imageArray = @[@"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @""];


     _dataArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
     _dataArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
     _dataArray3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

     for(int i=0;i < 100; i++){
       [_dataArray1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)(arc4random() % 10)]];
       [_dataArray2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)(arc4random() % 10)]];
       [_dataArray3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)(arc4random() % 10)]];
}
}
...
```

And in the UIPickerView Delegate Method:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UILabel *pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

//debug code
NSNumber *i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)_dataArray1[row]];

if (component == 0) {
    pickerLabel.text = _imageArray[(int)_dataArray1[row]];
}else if (component == 1){
    pickerLabel.text = _imageArray[(int)_dataArray2[row]];
}else{
    pickerLabel.text = _imageArray[(int)_dataArray3[row]];
}

return pickerLabel;
}
```

When I run my code,the console out put '**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'**'.And I add a debug code just like the comment

```
   NSNumber *i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)_dataArray1[row]];
```

I found when the i equals 146,the app crashed.I really get confused where the
'146' come from.And I also type a '**po _dataArray1**' in console, there is no 146 in the _dataArray1.Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_dataArray1[row] intValue];
```

instead of

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)_dataArray1[row];
```

casting NSNumber into int may sometimes return Garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber to Int should be like the below:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UILabel *pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

//debug code
NSNumber *i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_dataArray1[row].intValue];

if (component == 0) {
    pickerLabel.text = _imageArray[_dataArray1[row].intValue];
}else if (component == 1){
    pickerLabel.text = _imageArray[_dataArray2[row].intValue];
}else{
    pickerLabel.text = _imageArray[_dataArray3[row].intValue];
}

return pickerLabel;
}
```